# Consulta SQL no VBA Excel

Tags: query, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

bom dia!

Primeiramente gostaria de dizer que não entendo quase nada de Visual Basic e que tudo que aprendi até agora foi na raça em fóruns. Então se isso for muito simples de resolver, me perdoem.

Agora ao problema. Eu tinha uma planilha em Excel, onde eu cadastrava os cartões de benefícios recebidos na empresa. Então eu resolvi criar um formulário para facilitar a inclusão das informações. Além disso eu peguei essa planilha e migrei os dados para um banco de dados criado no Access. Já consegui criar o Formulário:

[image: Formulário para inclusão dos dados]

Agora o que eu quero é criar uma consulta (SELECT *FROM) e um UPDATE (caso algum dado seja digitado erroneamente).

Entretanto eu empaquei na criação da consulta.

Seguem abaixo os códigos que usei.

Aqui eu crio a conexão com o Banco de Dados:

```
Public enderecoDB       As String
Public SQL              As String
Public rs               As ADODB.Recordset
Public mConn            As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub SU_Conectadb()

On Error GoTo erro

enderecoDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\database\controlecartoes.mdb"

Set mConn = New ADODB.Connection

mConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"
mConn.Open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Exit Sub

erro:

MsgBox "Erro! Não Foi Possível Conectar ao Banco De Dados" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Number & Err.Description, vbCritical

Set mConn = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub

Public Sub Desconectabd()

On Error Resume Next

mConn.Close

Set mConn = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Aqui eu insiro as informações do formulário na planilha:

```
Private Sub btn_incluir_Click()
SQL = ""

SQL = "INSERT INTO controle (TP_BENEFICIO, BP, CPF, NOME, DTADM, FILIAL, NRCARTAO, SOLICPOR, DTRECEBE,"

SQL = SQL & " DTENVIOBS, ENVIADORETIRADO, NMMINUTA)"

SQL = SQL & "VALUES ("

SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.modalidadebox.Value & "', "
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmcolabor.boxbp.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmcolabor.cpfbox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmcolabor.boxnome.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmcolabor.dtadmbox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmcolabor.filialbox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.nmcartaobox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.soliciporbox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.dtrecebebox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.dtenviobsbox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.enviadoretiradobox.Value & "',"
SQL = SQL & "'" & controlectform.frmsegndvia.nmminutabox.Value & "' "
SQL = SQL & ")"

mConn.Execute SQL

MsgBox "Inclusão realizada com sucesso!"

End Sub
```

E essa foi minha tentativa de retornar os dados de volta ao formulário:

```
Private Sub btn_consulta_Click()

SQL = "SELECT [controle$].NOME FROM [controle$] WHERE [controle$].BP =" & controlectform.dadoscolaborpgconsulta.nmbpbox.Value

DoCmd.RunSQL "SQL"

controlectform.dadoscolaborpgconsulta.nomecolaboradorbox.Value = SQL

End Sub
```

Só que ao clicar no botão consulta é apresentado esse erro:

[image: Erro VBA doCmd.RunSQL]

Eu já tentei fazer a consulta de várias formas e sempre obtive esse erro.

Basicamente o que eu quero fazer é:

informar o BP ou CPF e ao clicar em consultar os dados retornam no formulário.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz de como executar a consulta eu agradeço.

ps.: testei a consulta direto no access e funcionou.

Comment: Inicialmente faça um comando simples:

    Private Sub btn_consulta_Click()     
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM CONTROLE"
            DoCmd.RunSQL "SQL"
        End Sub 
e poste o resultado.

Comment: Reginaldo, realizei o teste proposto e retornou a mesma mensagem de erro. 

Erro em tempo de execução '2046':

Answer (score 1):

Porque o comando `DoCmd.RunSQL` não serve para fazer `SELECT` ele deve ser utilizado para fazer `DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE` ou `SELECT INTO`

Para fazer `selects` faça algo parecido com isso:

```
sSQL = "SELECT [controle$].NOME FROM [controle$] WHERE [controle$].BP =" & controlectform.dadoscolaborpgconsulta.nmbpbox.Value

Dim rs As DAO Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)


 strText = rs.Fields(1)
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Reginaldo,

Tentei dessa forma mas ainda assim tive alguns erros.

Após mais algumas pesquisas na internet encontrei algo que me serviu perfeitamente.

Deixo abaixo o código para caso mais alguém precise:

```
Function SelectNome(Tabela As String, Campo As String, Criterios As String) As Variant

    Dim Resultado As Variant

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

    cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    sql = "SELECT " & Tabela & "." & Campo & " From " & Tabela & " where " & Criterios & ";"

    rs.Open sql, cn

    i = 2
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            Resultado = rs(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    cn.Close

    SelectNome = Resultado

    controlectform.nomecolaboradorbox.Value = Resultado

End Function
```

Ao clicar no botão de consulta ele retorna o nome no campo correspondente do formulário.

[image: Consulta com êxito]

Os campos estão desabilitados pois essa tela será, a princípio, só para consulta. Caso algum dado esteja errado será necessário clicar em alterar para habilitar os campos.

Agradeço o seu apoio.